# Onvif управление зуммом

Tags: c#, камера, onvif

Я пишу программу управления IP-камерами через протокол **ONVIF**.

Управляю через порт [PTZ](https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl) используя функцию `ContinuousMove`, но на разных камерах она работает по разному. К примеру, на одной камере все работает хорошо, а на другой зуммится до конца. При использовании функции `RelativeMove` картина обратная.

Для функции `AbsoluteMove` не могу достать из камеры текущее положение зумма.

Буду рад любому совету, исходники при необходимости предоставлю.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы приложили код управления камерой к вопросу, так отвечающему будет проще понять и поправить ваше код, вставьте текстом в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом: использовал функцию GetStatus для получения текущего значения зумма и AbsoluteMove для непосредственно управления зуммом.

```
    public void StartZoom (Direction direction)
    {
      if (zoomEnabled_)
      {
        var ptzStatus_ = ptzClient_.GetStatus(profile_.token);
        moveVector_.PanTilt = ptzStatus_.Position.PanTilt;
        moveVector_.Zoom = ptzStatus_.Position.Zoom;

        var zoomSpace = options_.Spaces.AbsoluteZoomPositionSpace;
        var minZoom = zoomSpace[0].XRange.Min;
        var maxZoom = zoomSpace[0].XRange.Max;

        moveVelocity_.Zoom.x = 0;

        if (direction.HasFlag(Direction.ZoomIn))
        {
          if (ptzStatus_.Position.Zoom.x + 1 / 20F <= maxZoom)
          {
            moveVelocity_.Zoom.x = velocityZoomIn_;
            moveVector_.Zoom.x += 1 / 20F;
          }
          else
          {
            moveVector_.Zoom.x = maxZoom;
          }

        }
        else if (direction.HasFlag(Direction.ZoomOut))
        {
          if (ptzStatus_.Position.Zoom.x - 1 / 20F >= minZoom)
          {
            moveVelocity_.Zoom.x = velocityZoomOut_;
            moveVector_.Zoom.x -= 1 / 20F;
          }
          else
          {
            moveVector_.Zoom.x = minZoom;
          }
        }

        ptzClient_.AbsoluteMove(profile_.token, moveVector_, moveVelocity_);
      }
    }
```